# call other shortcode in the email contactform7 send

Tags: shortcode, plugin-contact-form-7

Please advise how I can call other shortcode in the email contactform7 send.

Here is my code:

```
function show_bill( $wpcf7 ) {

   $wpcf7 .= do_shortcode('[pdf-embedder url=http://xyxy.com/home/invoices/TCH6418086-2015Sep28_Oct04.pdf]');

   return $wpcf7 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to embed a PDF with an invoice inside a contactform7 email response?

Answer (score 1):

For sending in mails you can use below code:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_special_mail_tags', 'show_bill', 10, 3 );
```

For more details please follow below links:

[Custom shortcode in emails](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-shortcode-in-emails)

[Short code in form](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-include-custom-shortcodes-in-form)

[Contact form 7 custom shortcodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179355/wordpress-contact-form-7-custom-shortcodes)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand a little more, such as what that filter is for, and where you got the `show_bill` from?

Comment: Please check question `show_bill` is in question, the name of function and details are provided in links. thanks!